# How to tell who stole the focus from your activity

Tags: android, android-activity

For reasons outside of my control (so, please no "you're doing it wrong" replies), my Android app needs to play *extremely* nicely, i.e. when a user hits the home button, my app needs to go away and release all of its resources (which are heayy, more than 1GB RAM consumption etc). It seemed calling finish() in onPause() would do the trick, but here's the problem: onPause() and onStop() also get called when I start an activity of my own, e.g. a preference activity, for which I just want to normally return.

So, my problem is: How can I determine the reason for losing the focus? I can think of two options, neither of which are pretty:

1. Keep state, i.e. the new activity sets some global flag that I can check in the "covered" activity so it doesn't stop when onStop() gets called. Annoying because every new activity of mine would have to do that.
2. Use the ActivityManager to check the top activity, and if it's one of mine, don't commit suicide. Maybe better, but the documentation *heavily* discourages use of the ActivityManager for this type of stuff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to [use `onUserLeaveHint()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29). It may cover some scenarios (e.g., HOME), but not all (e.g., incoming phone call).

> please no "you're doing it wrong" replies

IMHO, "more than 1GB RAM consumption" is already "doing it wrong" for a Play Store app. Specialized apps (e.g., specific enterprise scenarios, dedicated hardware) might be able to get away with that.

Comment: You can't get that app on the Play Store :)
This is for a military application, we're doing heavy computing on the phone. 
Thanks though, I was not aware of this callback!

Comment: @user3512600: Then I'd be handling this more from the standpoint of your ROM mod, rather than at the app level.

Comment: That falls into the "totally outside of my control" category.

Comment: Just to follow up on this suggestion, onUserLeaveHint() does not distinguish between home button push and regular UI button push. Both count as "user initiated action" (of course rightly so), but it annoyingly means the function gets called in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

One approach for option 1 that will make it less annoying to implement and maintain would be to use [`Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks%29). At least this way you don't have to implement this logic multiple times in multiple classes or unnecessarily force your activities into a single otherwise unrelated base class.

Not that I necessarily endorse this option. Also note you'll need API 14+.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Yeah, you could have one central function that gets called with these callbacks from the different activities, thus at least have the state-keeping in one place.